# How to use two differnet queues in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, wso2-esb

I have Websphere MQ and Active MQ configured in WSO2 ESB. I want to get message from Websphere MQ and send it to ActiveMQ. When I used Websphere MQ Queue name to get the messages it is automatically creating a Queue in ActiveMQ and sing that and not accessing Websphere MQ. How to use two different Queue as I have mentioned?

My proxy to read message from Queue:

```html
<proxy name="read_from_MQ" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <description/>
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <log level="full" />
      <store messageStore="JMSMS" />
      <!--ActiveMQ message store-->
    </inSequence>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">QUEUE</parameter>
  <!-- Webshpere MQ Queue but it creates a new one in ActiveMQ -->
</proxy>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usecase is to pick the messages from Webshpere MQ Queue and store it in a ActiveMQ message store. Have you configured listeners and senders for ActiveMQ in $ESB_HOME/repository/axis2/axis2.xml? If you did, you need to revert them. You only need to set up the broker server itself and do not need to configure the listeners and senders in axis2.xml for a message store. In your case, you only need to configure these for Webshpere MQ Queue, not for ActiveMQ. Please go through [1] for more details on this (specially `Configure the Broker Server` section)

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores